# What special things does the L do for a C strings, except of marking it as wide string?

Tags: c, string, arm, c-strings

There is a wide string represented as `unsigned short*` as in the code:

```
/// data type unsigned short, data length 2 byte
typedef unsigned short MI_U16; 

static int _MI_PVR_UniStrlen(MI_U16 *pu16Str) {
    int iStrlen = 0;
    bool bStrEnd = false;
    MI_U16 *pu16UniStr = NULL;
    if (pu16Str == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    pu16UniStr = (MI_U16*)pu16Str;
    while(bStrEnd == false) {
        if (*pu16UniStr == 0) {
            bStrEnd = true;
            break;
        } else {
            pu16UniStr++; //changing this line to pu16UniStr += sizeof(MI_U16); makes correct output 5
        }
        iStrlen++;
    }
    return iStrlen;
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned short* str = L"abcde";
    int l1 = _MI_PVR_UniStrlen(str);
    printf("\nle1 = %d\n", l1); // 1
    return 0;
}
```

Output is 1, which means that pointer `pu16UniStr` in the function is incremented by 1 byte only, and because second byte is `0` the loop is stopped doing only 1 iteration.

I can't get a clue about why it behaves this way ?

Shouldn't `L` tell the compiler to increment a pointer by 2 byte ?

Also, the fact that after changing increment of `pu16UniStr` (see the comment) we get correct output of 5, makes me think that the function is implemented incorrectly, am I right ?

**p.s.**

there are no chances to use something like `wcslen()`

Comment: Why do you believe the output of `1` to indicate that the pointer was only incremented by 1 byte? Hint: it's an `unsigned short`-pointer .

Comment: @EOF I explained that in that in the question...

Comment: @EOF before saying something, please run the code. The first char is 0x61 0x00, it encounters 0x00 (second half of the wide char) and stops, isnt?

Comment: You should use `wchar_t *` instead of `unsigned short *`,  and make sure you enable standard compiler diagnostics   (if there is a type mismatch in pointer assignment it is an error, but some compilers default to a mode that doesn't give an error message)

Comment: Ok, I am deleting my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character constants prefixed with `L` have type `wchar_t`.  This type is most likely 4 bytes on your system.  So when you use an `unsigned short *` to index it, you only see half of the bytes for a given character.

Change the pointer type to `unsigned int` or `uint32_t`, or better yet just use `wchar_t`.

Comment: note, if this is the problem then `unsigned short* str = L"abcde";` should give a diagnostic message